# how to write a function for numpy matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix A and I need a function that will count (A[i,j]/sum of all elements in i-th column) - A[i,j]/sum of all elements in j-th row
and it for every element in A.

I've already tried to write something along the line of:

```
a = A.sum(axis=0) 
b = A.sum(axis=1) 

for i in A: 
    for j in i: 
        f = A[i,j]/a(i) - A[i,j]/b(j)
```

Comment: Could you say a little more about what you have tried?

Comment: yep, i tried to write smth like:
a=A.sum(axis=0)
b=A.sum(axis=1)
for i in A:
for j in i:
f=A[i,j]/a(i) - A[i,j]/b(j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could help:

```py
def f(i,j,A):
    return A[i,j] * ( 1. / np.sum(A[i,])  ) -  ( 1. / np.sum(A[:,j])  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look for a vectorized solution than looping through all elements

```
A/A.sum(axis=0)[np.newaxis,:] -  A/A.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
```

Suppose

```
In [35]: A = np.random.rand(10,3)
Out[35]:
array([[ 0.26070074,  0.58940996,  0.78665012],
       [ 0.7420538 ,  0.72214655,  0.66633183],
       [ 0.67189673,  0.67298124,  0.04628626],
       [ 0.93935375,  0.45030544,  0.38292913],
       [ 0.45410731,  0.26557299,  0.09573014],
       [ 0.99872912,  0.31092656,  0.46294278],
       [ 0.61108329,  0.71140089,  0.85548017],
       [ 0.80012964,  0.64749927,  0.3292407 ],
       [ 0.33229818,  0.01810878,  0.44460486],
       [ 0.86525557,  0.0569463 ,  0.43183502]])
```

You could do the following.

```
In [36]: A*(1/A.sum(axis=0)[np.newaxis,:] -  1/A.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis])
Out[36]:
array([[-0.12022572, -0.22751579, -0.3058817 ],
       [-0.23713606, -0.17649948, -0.16474676],
       [-0.3823249 , -0.33236228, -0.0229904 ],
       [-0.38921906, -0.1527391 , -0.13097127],
       [-0.48888156, -0.26594996, -0.09613741],
       [-0.41381789, -0.10546217, -0.15833642],
       [-0.18903571, -0.16660122, -0.20276794],
       [-0.33044427, -0.21874513, -0.11216096],
       [-0.36820095, -0.01870431, -0.46048657],
       [-0.5094047 , -0.02924623, -0.22300407]])
```